# padding top in bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using c3.js to generate a graph. I want to put an image on top of each bar, on the label. So that the image is shown well I would like the graphic to have a space in the top that gives me the possibility of having the image without leaving the svg

https://jsfiddle.net/ao2xojnx/

[image]

```
 var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ],
        labels:true,
        type:'bar'
    },
    axis: {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for doing this. Both have the same result and both need hardcoded values.

First way: set the `y axis` maximum:

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ],
        labels: true,
        type: 'bar'
      },
      axis: {
        y: {
          max: 700
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
#catImage {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Second way: set the `padding.top`:

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ],
        labels: true,
        type: 'bar'
      },
      axis: {
        y: {
          padding: {top:200, bottom:0}
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
#catImage {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Pay attention to the fact that, in both ways, you'll have extra ticks in the y axis.

Comment: can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230566/make-a-chart-of-x-vs-y-in-c3-js