# make a chart of X vs Y

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some points in x and others in y. I'm trying to make a chart as in the image I have. I want the points of the created graph can be joined. in c3.js I do not know how to plot X vs Y. How can I achieve something like my photo?

https://jsfiddle.net/8tqguqww/

```
var pointsx=[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
var pointsy=[2,3,4,7,8,9,8,7,3]

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    },
    point: {
        show: true
    }
});
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xGZO8Vx.jpg]

Comment: scatter plot can partially solve your problem but if you want to join points via  path   then you need to move to d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of this kind of chart is *scatter plot*.

Therefore, you'll have to specify the type:

```
type: 'scatter'
```

And tell C3 what are the data array pairs:

```
xs: {
  data1: "data2"
},
columns: [
  ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
  ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
],
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qrqquhvd/

EDIT: Because of the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230566/make-a-chart-of-x-vs-y#comment79433651_46230566) in your question I just realized that you have this requirement: *"I want the points of the created graph can be joined"*. The answer is simple: it's impossible using just C3. You'll have to do that with D3 code... an even better idea is just dropping C3 and doing everything with D3.

Comment: your answers are the best! they have helped me learn a lot. you are a genius

Comment: can you help me with this please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257892/generate-an-animation-when-i-add-a-new-point-to-a-line-in-using-d3-js  
If you do not know it, nobody will know XD

Comment: I saw that question. Unfortunately that's too much work for a S.O. question, in my opinion.

Comment: I researched and I could almost solve my problem but now I get a new one. Can you give me a hand, please?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287131/the-line-is-repainted-in-d3-js